# How to properly INSERT INTO MySQL Using PHP Variables

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I'm having a problem with my personal server where I'm trying to create a database for the decade old binders I have for the Yu-Gi-Oh! Trading Card Game (haven't played in years). In testing the INSERT INTO, I keep running across a particular problem...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Magic'(Name, Description, Card_ID, Pack, P_ID, Quantity) VALUES ('Post', 'Post ' at line 1

Now my code outputs properly when I comment out the query function and echo to my webpage, but I keep getting the above mysql_error() message being displayed.

My code snippet is as follows...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
mysql_connect("localhost", "my_username", "my_password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("my_db") or die(mysql_error());

function clean_string($value) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$Show = clean_string($_POST['show']);
$Table = clean_string($_POST['table']);
$Insert_M_T = $_POST['insert_magic_traps'];
$Insert_Monster = $_POST['insert_monster_effect'];

$Insert_Card_Type = clean_string($_POST['I_Type']);
$Insert_Card_Name = clean_string($_POST['I_Card_Name']);
$Insert_Description = clean_string($_POST['I_C_Description']);
$Insert_Card_ID = clean_string($_POST['I_Card_ID']);
$Insert_CardPack = clean_string($_POST['I_C_Pack']);
$Insert_PackID = clean_string($_POST['I_C_P_ID']);
$Insert_Quantity = clean_string($_POST['I_C_Quantity']);

if(isset($Insert_M_T)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO '$Insert_Card_Type'(Name, Description, Card_ID, Pack, P_ID, Quantity) VALUES ('$Insert_Card_Name', '$Insert_Description', '$Insert_Card_ID', '$Insert_CardPack', '$Insert_PackID', '$Insert_Quantity')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<center><h2>Record added to Table: $Insert_Card_Type</h2></center>";
    echo "<center><table><tr><th>Name:</th><td>$Insert_Card_Name</td></tr><tr><th>Description:</th><td>$Insert_Description</td></tr><tr><th>Card ID:</th><td>$Insert_Card_ID</td></tr><tr><th>Pack:</th><td>$Insert_CardPack</td></tr><tr><th>Pack ID Number</th><td>$Insert_PackID</td></tr><tr><th>Quantity:</th><td>$Insert_Quantity</td></tr></table></center>";
}
?>
//more html and php code
<?php
} else {
    echo "<h1><center><font color=#ff0000 >ACCESS DENIED!!!</font></center></h1>";
    echo "<h2><center><a href=index.php >Login Here!</a></center></h2>";
}
?>
```

Any advice would be helpful. I've tried searching for how to get around this problem, but to no avail. I feel like this is a simple fix, but I'm missing it. Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

~DanceLink

Comment: you should switch to mysqli or pdo since mysql_ functions are deprecated. any tutorial on mysqli or pdo will clarify sanitizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `$Insert_Card_Type` (Name, Description, Card_ID, Pack, P_ID, Quantity) 
  VALUES ('$Insert_Card_Name', '$Insert_Description', '$Insert_Card_ID', '$Insert_CardPack', '$Insert_PackID', '$Insert_Quantity')
```

Backticks around `$Insert_Card_Type`, not single quotes.

Comment: +1 The MySQL error is returned because the tablename is enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @zdhickman, you Sir (or Ma'am) are awesome! thank you that worked!

Comment: Also, to those who suggested mysqli, I will consider it, I have to research it though as I'm used to mysql. Thank you everyone! :D